Configuration of Keycloak and Passport on a Nestjs Project
CONTEXT: we have a project based on Docker Containers, front and back are done with their dockerfile, that are called in the compose.yaml (we have 3 dir, front, back and infrastructure (where compose.yaml is)).
Our Front end is developed in Ionic, with Angular-Standalone framework and capacitor for mobile dev.
Our Back end is developed in NestJs (with express) linked to our postgres db.
We manage Authentication with Keycloak (with keycloak-openid-connect library), and sessions with Passport (that saves them on a Redis db).
At the moment we think that it's all configured correctly and working, in fact it writes on the redis db, with the login data when we log in.
QUESTION: Our problem is that we initialize all the "pieces" of the authentication strategies (keycloak to nestjs, sessions with passport, redis and the named 'keycloak' strategy (extending PassportStrategy from nestjs/passport) that we use as an authentication guard with @UseGuards(AuthGuard('keycloak')) on the controllers) in the main.ts file, and we think that we are doing something wrong in the interaction with the nestjs framework.
We've been working mainly on adapting keycloak to nest since keycloak's official node adapter has been deprecated for a while, and it's taking quite some time to understand how all the parts we've found can fit together nicely to use sessions.
//main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { httpsOptions });
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }));

  const { httpAdapter } = app.get(HttpAdapterHost);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new PrismaClientExceptionFilter(httpAdapter));
  // app.useGlobalGuards();
  app.enableCors();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, swaggerConfig);
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger_k3p', app, document);


  //PASSPORT conf
  setupPassport(app);

  // REDIS configuration
  redisClient.connect();
  console.log('post redis connection');
  configureSession(app);

  // KEYCLOAK configuration
  setupKeycloak(app);


  await app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0'); // lo '0.0.0.0' è per testing da mobile su rete locale con back su computer
  console.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
bootstrap();

//passport.middleware.ts
export function setupPassport(app) {
  app.use(passport.initialize());

  const KeycloakStrategy = PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'keycloak');
  console.log(keycloakConfig);

  passport.use(
    new KeycloakStrategy(
      keycloakConfigPassport,
      (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        return done(null, profile);
      },
    ),
  );

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
}

//session.config.ts
export function configureSession(app) {
  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
      secret: 'your-secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { secure: true }, // Set to true if using HTTPS
    }),
  );
}

//keycloak.middleware.ts
export function setupKeycloak(app) {
  app.use(auth(keycloakConfig));
}

We think that the configuration is wrong, since serializeUser & deserializeUser functions don't seem to do anything.
Furthermore, Everytime we login through keycloak, passport seems to generate a new session token, instead of refreshing the old one.
